# On Facebook sharing got exception android.webkit.WebView.onWindowFocusChanged

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, android-webview

I have done facebook integration in my app and it is working fine for me. But when I click on the clear credentials button and after that again want to login to share the content the app crashed and giving the exception. Below is the exception detail. I searched on google but didn't get any satisfactory ans.

```
11-06 17:25:32.074: E/AndroidRuntime(410): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-06 17:25:32.074: E/AndroidRuntime(410):  at android.webkit.WebView.onWindowFocusChanged(WebView.java:4177)
11-06 17:25:32.074: E/AndroidRuntime(410):  at android.view.View.dispatchWindowFocusChanged(View.java:3788)
11-06 17:25:32.074: E/AndroidRuntime(410):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowFocusChanged(ViewGroup.java:658)
11-06 17:25:32.074: E/AndroidRuntime(410):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowFocusChanged(ViewGroup.java:662)
11-06 17:25:32.074: E/AndroidRuntime(410):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowFocusChanged(ViewGroup.java:662)
11-06 17:25:32.074: E/AndroidRuntime(410):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowFocusChanged(ViewGroup.java:662)
11-06 17:25:32.074: E/AndroidRuntime(410):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowFocusChanged(ViewGroup.java:662)
11-06 17:25:32.074: E/AndroidRuntime(410):  at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1921)
11-06 17:25:32.074: E/AndroidRuntime(410):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-06 17:25:32.074: E/AndroidRuntime(410):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-06 17:25:32.074: E/AndroidRuntime(410):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
11-06 17:25:32.074: E/AndroidRuntime(410):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-06 17:25:32.074: E/AndroidRuntime(410):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
11-06 17:25:32.074: E/AndroidRuntime(410):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
11-06 17:25:32.074: E/AndroidRuntime(410):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
11-06 17:25:32.074: E/AndroidRuntime(410):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Please help me to find out why this exception is coming and how can resolve that. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Your Problem is you don't have registered your application on Facebook, i have face also this problem , now i have create a new app and change key and that is working fine for me..

in my case, i was using the key of my previous application then shows this error, now i have created app on facebook with new packagename and class name, then in is working fine for me.. thanks